# why pthread_rwlock can acquire write lock recursively?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, pthreads, mutex

If I try to acquire write lock more than one time in the same thread, it always succeed.

Below is the exmample code, what I expect is that it will hang up when it try to acquire the write lock second time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  pthread_rwlock_t rwlock_;
  pthread_rwlockattr_t rwlock_attr;
  pthread_rwlockattr_init(&rwlock_attr);
  pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np(&rwlock_attr, PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_WRITER_NONRECURSIVE_NP);
  pthread_rwlock_init(&rwlock_, &rwlock_attr);

  pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock_);
  pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&rwlock_);  // should blocked here
}
```

But it acquired the write lock twice. And no matter how do I change the attr the result is the same.

If I start another thread and both thread try to acquire the write lock, then one of the threads will be blocked. So **does it means pthread_rwlock can identify different thread?**

Also I've tried `boost::shared_lock`

```
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/lock_types.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/pthread/shared_mutex.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  boost::shared_mutex mtx;
  boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> wlock(mtx);
  boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> wlock2(mtx);

}
```

then my program will be blocked when it tried to acquire the write lock second time. So the behavior is different from `pthread_rwlock`.

I wonder how are they implemented internally. Is it possible to distinguish different thread? And what's the standard behavior a read/write lock should have?

Comment: So you tried *different* synchronization options and now you wonder why they are *different*? Well. They are different because they are *different*. Why would you expect different things to do the same thing? There is not just one way of doing things and the things you tried do things differently.

Comment: The manual for `pthread_rwlock` notes that:  _"...The results are undefined if the calling thread already holds the lock at the time the call is made...."_  So don't try to do it;  source: https://www.daemon-systems.org/man/pthread_rwlock.3.html